# Construction of bounded sequence in $l_{2}$ which does not have convergent subsequence

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

As title says I am looking for sequence in space of square summable sequences which is bounded but does not have convegent subsequence. Any hint? Thanks.

Comment: Canonical basis vectors.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the usual orthonormal basis $(u_n) $ of $l_2$.